# Unexpected value 'MatMenu' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

I'm getting this runtime error from the browser console.

But it doesn't make any sense because I'm already importing what I need to from @angular/material.

Here is my NgModule.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatMenu } from "@angular/material";
import { MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatSortModule, MatTableModule, MatFormFieldModule } from "@angular/material";
import {CdkTableModule} from "@angular/cdk/table";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    MatMenu

  ],
  providers: [HttpClientModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to import `{MatMenuModule}` not `MatMenu`

Try this:

`import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';`

```
 imports: [
   MatMenuModule
 ]
```

See [Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api)